# Can there be a triangle ABC if $\frac{\cos A}{1}=\frac{\cos B}{2}=\frac{\cos C}{3}$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Can there be a triangle ABC if  $$\frac{\cos A}{1}=\frac{\cos B}{2}=\frac{\cos C}{3}\;?$$ Equating the ratios to $k$ we get $\cos A=k$, $\cos B=2k$, $\cos C=3k$.
Then the identity $$\cos^2A+\cos^2B+\cos^2C+2\cos A \cos B \cos C=1 \implies 12k^3+14k^2-1=0$$
$f(k)=12k^3+14k^2-1$ being monotonic for $k>0$ can have at most one real positive root. Further, $f(0)=-1, f(1/3)=1>0$, so there will be one real root in $(0,1/3)$. Hence all three cosines will be positive and less that 1, for a unque triangle to be possible.

What can be other ways to solve  this question?

Comment: Information [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3834491).

Comment: Please write a clear question. If the question is related to a problem, and you even have one solution for it, please write the problem in the text (not only in the title) making clear what is given and what is wanted. Then the question should be more precise. ("the same" is rather unclear...)

Comment: OK, I have rephrased it now.

Comment: Good solution. Really want alternatives, maybe constructive one?

Comment: You can use the triangle inequality, that $1 + 2 = 3$, $1 + 3 > 2$, and that $2 + 3 > 1$, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(k) = \cos^{-1}(k) + \cos^{-1}(2k) + \cos^{-1}(3k)$ is continuous on $k\in [0,1/3]$. Since $f(0) = 3\pi/2 > \pi$ and $f(1/3) \approx 2.07 < \pi$, the intermediate value theorem tells us that there is a $k \in (0,1/3)$ such that $f(k) = \pi$. This is the desired triangle.

Comment: (+1) it would be much more beautiful if you can say that $f(1/3)<\pi$,analytically,$f(1/3)=\cos^{-1}(1/3) + \cos^{-1}(2/3) + 0$.since, $0<\cos^{-1}(1/3),\cos^{-1}(2/3) <\pi/2$,then $0<\cos^{-1}(1/3) + \cos^{-1}(2/3)<\pi$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align} 
\frac{\cos A}{1}&
=\frac{\cos B}{2}=\frac{\cos C}{3}
=\frac{\cos A+\cos B+\cos C}{6}
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
6\cos A&=\cos A+\cos B+\cos C
=\frac{r}{R}+1=
v+1
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}
where $r$ and $R$ are inradius and circumradius
of the corresponding $\triangle ABC$,
$v=\tfrac{r}{R}\in(0,\tfrac12]$ for a valid triangle.

Hence,

\begin{align} 
\cos A&=\frac{v+1}6\in(0,\tfrac14)
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
\cos B&=2\cos A =\frac{v+1}3 \in(0,\tfrac12)
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
\cos C&=3\cos A=\frac{v+1}2 \in(0,\tfrac34)
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

From known identity
\begin{align} 
\cos A\cos B\cos C
&=\tfrac14(u^2-(v+2)^2)
\tag{6}\label{6}
,
\end{align}
where $u=\tfrac\rho{R}$,
and $\rho$ is semiperimeter of $\triangle ABC$,
we can express $u^2$ in terms of $v$:

\begin{align} 
\tfrac1{36}(v+1)^3
&=\tfrac14(u^2-(v+2)^2)
,\\
u^2&=
\tfrac19v^3+\tfrac43v^2+\tfrac{13}3 v+\tfrac{37}9
\tag{7}\label{7}
,
\end{align}

and with the help of

\begin{align} 
\cos A\cos B+\cos B\cos C+\cos C\cos A
&= \tfrac14(u^2+v^2)-1
\tag{8}\label{8}
\end{align}

we arrive at the cubic equation in $v$

\begin{align}
v^3+10v^2+17v-10&=0
,
\end{align}

which has only one positive solution

\begin{align}
v&=
\tfrac{14}3\cos\left(
\tfrac\pi3
-\tfrac13\arctan\left(\tfrac9{100}\sqrt{1329}\right)
\right)
-\tfrac{10}3
\approx 0.458757
.
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
u(v) &= \tfrac13\sqrt{v^3+12v^2+39v+37}
\approx 2.52792343
,\\
u_{\min}(v)&=
\sqrt{27-(5-v)^2-2\sqrt{(1-2v)^3}}
\approx 2.5158959
,\\
u_{\max}(v)&=
\sqrt{27-(5-v)^2+2\sqrt{(1-2v)^3}}
\approx 2.53465839
,
\end{align}

so indeed we have a unique valid triangle with given properties.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not as sophisticated.

But for any angle $\frac \pi 2 > A > \frac \pi 3$ we can have $\cos A$ be any value from $0 < \cos A < \frac 1 2$ we can have $B_A= \cos^{-1} (2\cos A)$ so $\cos B_A = 2\cos A$ and $\frac \pi 2 > B_A > 0$ and $0 < \cos B < 1$.

These can be two angles of a triangle with the third angle being $C_A= \pi - A - B_A=\pi -A - \cos^{-1}(2\cos A)$.

We need $\cos C_A = 3\cos A$ or $\cos C_A - 3\cos A = 0$.  Is that possible?

Well,  If $A = \frac \pi 2$ then $\cos A =0$ and $B_A = \cos^{-1} 0 = \frac \pi 2$ and $C_A = 0$ and $\cos C_A = 1$ and $\cos C_A - 3\cos A = 1$.

And If $A=\frac \pi 3$ then $\cos A = \frac 12$ and $B_ = \cos^{-1} 1 = 0$ and $C_A = \frac {2\pi}3$ and $\cos C_A = -\frac 12 $ and $\cos C_1 - 3\cos A = -2$.

But $\cos C_A -3\cos A$ is continuous, so there must be a value of $A$ between $\frac \pi 2$ and $\frac \pi 3$ where $\cos C_A - 3\cos A = 0$.

And for that $A$ we will have $B_A = \cos^{-1}(2\cos A)$ and $\cos B_A = 2\cos A$ and $\cos C_A = 3\cos A$.

Ta-da....

(You never said you wanted to *find* it; just that you wanted to know one exists.  Well, one must exist by continuity and intermediate value theorem but this argument gives utterly no method of *finding* it.)